# One mouse will wake PC from sleep, another won't

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, sleep

I have 2 USB mice, and I've noticed that one of them is capable of waking my Windows 10 PC from S3 sleep, while the other isn't (same PC, same USB port). Pure curiosity has me wondering what makes the difference. Does the device need to support some sort of low power mode for this to work? Is it related to the driver? For what it's worth, "Allow this device to wake the computer" is checked in Device Manager for both.

Comment: Some mice auto shutoff until a button is pushed. Some won't power-up if the USB adapter doesn't have power, so you might need to enable USB power while in standby.